# Problems with class functions' arguments Python

Tags: python, class, arguments

I've been experiencing issues of the TypeError kind while attempting to call functions defined in a class. The error is: `TypeError: p() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

```
class HTMLGen:
    def p(text):
        return ("<p>%s</p>" % text)
    def a(text):
        return ("<a>%s</a>" % text)
    def b(text):
        return ("<b>%s</b>" % text)
    def title(text):
        return ("<title>%s</title>" % text)
    def comment(text):
        return ("<!--%s-->" % text)
    def div(text):
        return ("<div>%s</div>" % text)
    def span(text):
        return ("<span>%s</span>" % text)
    def body(text):
        return ("<body>%s</body>" % text)
```

Then, after importing the HTMLGen class and attempting to use the `HTMLGen.p(t)` function this way

```
>>> import htmlgen
>>> website = htmlgen.HTMLGen()
>>> paragraph = website.p("Hello World!")
```

and pressing Enter, I get the aforementioned error. Does anyone know why the HTMLGen.p() and other functions are getting more than one argument, and what is the easiest way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Methods in a class are always passed in `self` plus whatever other arguments you gave it. `self` plus `text` is two arguments, but your methods only accept *one* argument. Add `self` to all of them or make them static functions. Why are you putting this in a class in the first place?

Comment: Consider that `website.p("Hello World!")` is, to a first approximation, equivalent to `HTMLGen.p(website, "Hello World!")`, and you'll understand why the method needs to be defined with two parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you create functions inside class it must have self argument in all functions which are inside the class.

```
class HTMLGen:
    def p(self,text):
        return ("<p>%s</p>" % text)
    def a(self,text):
        return ("<a>%s</a>" % text)
    def b(self,text):
        return ("<b>%s</b>" % text)
    def title(self,text):
        return ("<title>%s</title>" % text)
    def comment(self,text):
        return ("<!--%s-->" % text)
    def div(self,text):
        return ("<div>%s</div>" % text)
    def span(self,text):
        return ("<span>%s</span>" % text)
    def body(self,text):
        return ("<body>%s</body>" % text)
```

Comment: Thanks! I do remember learning about the `self` argument but never thought about using it here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an additional parameter, by convention called self. It refers to the object itself. Many programming languages use the keyword `this` instead.

```
def span(self, text):
    return ("<span>%s</span>" % text)
```